# How to fix module resolution when implementing `unplugin-vue-components`?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vite

I'm working on getting `unplugin-vue-components` working with my project so I don't have to register all of my first-party plugin components all through my individual projects... I'm having trouble getting `Vite` to recognize the named/exported Vue Components in my SFCs...

Console Log:

```
An error occurred: The requested module '/flighter/resources/js/components/LinkWrapper.vue' does not provide an export named 'FlighterLinkWrapper' SyntaxError: The requested module '/flighter/resources/js/components/LinkWrapper.vue' does not provide an export named 'FlighterLinkWrapper'
```

From my generated `components.d.ts` file:

```js
// ...
FlighterLink:typeof import('flighter/js/components/Link.vue')['FlighterLink'];
FlighterLinkWrapper:typeof import('flighter/js/components/LinkWrapper.vue')['FlighterLinkWrapper'];
FlighterMapLink:typeof import('flighter/js/components/links/Map.vue')['FlighterMapLink'];
// ...
```

From  my `vite.config.ts` file:

```js
// ...
resolve: {
    alias: [
        {find: '@js/', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, `resources/js`) + '/'},
        {find: /^@?flighter\//, replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, `flighter/resources`) + '/'}
    ],
    extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.json']
},
// ...
```

The contents of my `flighter/resources/js/components/LinkWrapper.vue` file includes:

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
// ...
</script>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
    name: 'FlighterLinkWrapper'
};
</script>
```

I've already confirmed that the issue is not with the Vue SFC trying to be resolved itself... something to do with the file not being interpreted properly, or a module name mismatch if that makes sense?

**My Dev Stack:**
`Laravel 10`/`InertiaJS 1`/`VueJS 3`/`ViteJS 4`/`TailwindCSS 3`/`Vitest 0.31`/`VitePress 1`/`Typescript`/`SSR`
`FontAwesome Pro 6`/`Ploi.io`/`Qodana`/`Cypress`/`ImgIX`/`HubSpot`/`SendGrid`/`SignEasy`/`Stripe`

**TL;DR;** Anyone have experience setting up `unplugin-vue-components` in one of their projects?

Answer (score 0):

As I know ,this plug find a component only by component path but name,so you need let the component using name same to the path name ,try to change the file name to FlighterLinkWrapper.vue from LinkWrapper.vue

Answer (score -1):

First things first: did you configure vite to work with Vue, are sfc recognised when not using `unplugin-vue-components`?
If not make sure to install required dependencies:

- @vitejs/plugin-vue
- @vue/compiler-sfc (this one is responsible for compilation of vue
  single file components)

After having those installed update your `vite.config.js`, it should look something like this:

```
    import vuePlugin from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
    import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
    
    export default defineConfig({
      plugins: [
        vuePlugin(),
        Components({ /* options */ }),
      ]
    })
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: As mentioned in my OP, I have already ruled out issues with the SFC itself. My code was working 100% before attempting to implement `unplugin-vue-components`.